# How to change priority screen load inside a route file - react-navigation

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-navigation`.

now I want to change first `screen` load from inside of `StackNavigator`.

```
export const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  Phone: {
    screen: Phone,
  },
  Activation: {
    screen: Activation,
  }
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Phone',
});


export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: ContainerNavs,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: Notification,
  },
  Question: {
    screen: Question,
  },
  SelectContacts: {
    screen: SelectContacts,
  },
  Options: {
    screen: Options,
  },
},
{
  headerMode: 'none'
});





export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginStack,
  },
  Home:{
    screen: HomeStack,
  },
},{
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
}

);
```

but my router always load `Login` screen. but I want to load `Phone` screen.

Comment: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow)

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace The Screen and set first screen you want to load first .. that's it... so i just set `Phone` screen at the top of the `stacknavigator`

```
 export const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
   Phone: {
    screen: Phone,
   },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
   }, 
  Activation: {
   screen: Activation,
  }
},
{
 headerMode: 'none',
 initialRouteName: 'Phone',
 });
```